# Connection timeout Feign client while consuming huge data

Tags: hystrix, netflix-feign

I have a `FeignClient` which is configured to connect to 2 different services via Eureka service discovery.

It works perfectly fine for Service A but fails for Service B. Where Service B consumes `hbase` data and took nearly 5 minutes to complete. While consuming B it throws

> java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect.

On debugging I have found Service B have called and proceeded with its manipulation, but service which requested feign throws time out exception.